# Remove Doubles < Merge by distance?

Tags: modeling

Remove Doubles was removed and replaced with Merge by Distance? If, you set the value small enough it works the same and gives versatility.

Blender 2.8 Beta Version 5/13/19
[image]

Comment: Quoting @JtheNinja "To further clarify, this IS the remove doubles tool. It's the same tool under the hood, just with a new name and UI location".

Answer (score 1):

It's the same, only thing is that they changed the name.