# Removing Doubles is Gone in 2.8?

Tags: modeling

Is Removing doubles no longer an option in Blender 2.8? I just noticed it last night when I finally got a chance to use the final version of Blender.

Comment: Renamed to merge by distance

Comment: Please search before posting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/blender-2-80-remove-double-vertices-option-gone https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123185/2-8-remove-doubles-has-changed-to-merge-by-distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140892/remove-doubles-merge-by-distance

Comment: alt-m in the editor window